# Node.js calling MongoDB with aggregate find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have used SQL Server for a long time and just really learning MongoDB.  I am trying to figure out how to do the aggregate finds to get just the data I want.  Here is a sample from the database:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "user_id": "123-88",
  "department_id": "1",
  "type": "start",
  "time": "2017-04-20T19:40:15.329Z"
}

{
  "_id": "2",
  "user_id": "123-88",
  "department_id": "1",
  "type": "stop",
  "time": "2017-04-20T19:47:15.329Z"
}
```

What I want to do is find each unique user_id of department 1, only take the record with the latest time and tell me if they are oncall or not.  So in the example above user 123-88 is not oncall now.  How would you make this query?  I know you will need something like this:

```
TimeCard.aggregate([
    { $match: {department_id: req.query.department_id}},
    { $sort: { user_id: 1, time: 1 }},
    { $group: { _id: "$user_id", current_type: "$type", lastTime: { $last: "$time" }}}
    ], function(err, docs){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        else {res.json(docs);}
    });
```

But I keep erroring so I know I am not correct in my logic.  I know if I just have the match it works and if I add the sort it matches and sorts but the final group is not working.  Also what would I add to then only show the people that are oncall.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's not working because `current_type` must be an accumulator. If you want to have every `type` in `current_type` you can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push).

Comment: Thanks luisenrike.  I guess I dont understand.  I though the group would just give me back all the user_id, type and lasttime for each of the different user_ids.  Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count how many "types" per `user_id` you have, this can be done by `$sum`, if it's odd, the user is oncall, because there is a `start` without a `stop`. This approach is correct only if you always have a `stop` for a `start`.

```
TimeCard.aggregate([

    { $match: { department_id: req.query.department_id } },
    { $sort: { user_id: 1, time: 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: "$user_id", count_types: { $sum: 1 }, lastTime: { $last: "$time" }}},
    { $match: { count_types: { $mod: [ 2, 1 ] } } },

], function(err, docs) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); }
    else { res.json(docs); }
});
```

Comment: Yep that worked.  I see what you did (looking for odd since you would have a stop for every start).  I need to take a look at the $push also since there is more data I would like to send back if possible but this solution does give me the user_ids and lasttime when the users clocked in.  Thanks again for your quick reply.